# openCV ошибка функции распознавания

Tags: c++, opencv

Пишу в Visual Studio 2017 с opencv 3.3.0. Код взял с рабочих примеров, но там предыдущие версии opencv

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
Mat image;
image = imread("lena.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
imshow("cam", image);
// Load Face cascade (.xml file)
CascadeClassifier face_cascade;
face_cascade.load("С:/opencv/sources/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");

// Detect faces
std::vector<Rect> faces;
/*face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces,
    1.1, 2, 0
    //|CASCADE_FIND_BIGGEST_OBJECT
    //|CASCADE_DO_ROUGH_SEARCH
    //|CASCADE_DO_CANNY_PRUNING
    | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,
    Size(30, 30));*/
face_cascade.detectMultiScale(image, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

/*// Draw circles on the detected faces
for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++)
{
    Point center(faces[i].x + faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].y + faces[i].height*0.5);
    ellipse(image, center, Size(faces[i].width*0.5, faces[i].height*0.5), 0, 0, 360, Scalar(255, 0, 255), 4, 8, 0);
}*/

//namedWindow("Win");
waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего потому, что загружаете трёхканальное цветное изображение, а `detectMultiScale()` требует одноканальное (в оттенках серого).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

перед detectMultiscale конвертируйте картинку в GRAYSCALE с помощью cvtColor, или сразу загрузите как CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAY, также рекомендуется перед детектором применить к картинке фильтр equalizeHist